# Extra element at the end of my linked list

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

first of : sorry for my English, might be bad.

I got a school project in which I need to sort a list of numbers using linked lists.

Here's my struct :

```
typedef struct s_lst
{
    int     content;
    struct s_lst    *next;
} t_lst;
```

Problem here is that when I initialize it with my list of integers, I get an extra-element at the end, and I can't figure out why.

```
void    stack_ini(t_lst **sa, char **nbr)
{
    int i;
    t_lst *tmp;

    i = 0;
    tmp = *sa;

    while (nbr[i])
    {
        tmp->content = ft_atoi(nbr[i]);
        tmp->next = malloc(sizeof(t_lst));
        tmp = tmp->next;
        i++;
    }
    tmp->next = NULL;
    return ;
}
```

If I try to print the list 1-2-3-4 with this function

```
void    print_list(t_lst *lst)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (lst != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d Element in list : %d\n",i++, lst->content);
        lst= lst->next;
    }
    return ;
}
```

I'll get "1-2-3-4-0" as a result.

DO you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

In stack_init function, at the end of my while loop, I also tried to set tmp to NULL, even if it didnt made sense, and it resulted in a segfault.

I can't find what is this extra element doing here.

Thanks for your answers, and again, sorry for my English.

Comment: In your print function, change to `while (lst->next != NULL)`

Comment: but wouldnt it be like not printing the extra-element ?

Comment: You're allocating the linked list nodes incorrectly. You're assigning each value and then allocating the next node (even when it's not needed). Instead, you should be allocating the current node and then assigning content value to it.

Comment: You appear to allocate an element too many, otherwise there's no way `stack_ini` would work. Please provide a minimal runable demonstration of the problem.

Comment: How do you call your functions? If you are implementing a linked list, why do you call the function `stack_init`?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't demonstrate the problem, but you appear to allocate a node before calling `stack_ini`.

Fixed:

```c
t_lst *s = NULL;         // This was wrong.
stack_ini(&s, ...);
```

Once you do that, you have fix `stack_ini`.

```c
void stack_ini(t_lst **prev_next_ptr, char **nbr)
{
    for (; *nbr; ++nbr)
    {
        // Create a new node.
        t_lst *node = malloc(sizeof(t_lst));
        node->content = ft_atoi(*nbr);
        node->next = NULL;

        // Insert it into the list.
        *prev_next_ptr = node;
        prev_next_ptr = &( node->next );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Been struggling since three days witht this ! You are write i dit allocate my list one time before colling `Stack_ini`, sorry for not writing it I'd never thought it was that !